# How to read from text file and add into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, file-read

I am currently creating a quiz and am trying to get the data in my text file to be read using a quiz but I have hit a stumbling block in seeing how to get it to display the data ?

My Folder :

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder QuestionsFolder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

My Array :

```
String[] Questions = new String[10];
```

My Read Questions async function :

```
async Task ReadQuestions()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile sampleFile = await QuestionsFolder.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///Assets/Questions/myFile.txt");
        String Questions = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);

        // Data is contained
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
"questions_id","questions" 
1,"What is the correct element for Gold ?"
2,"What is the correct element for Hydrogen?"
3,"What is the correct element for Oxygen?
```

Any ideas on how to complete this so that it loads the questions from the text file and into the array?

Comment: We'd need to know how the file is formatted. You'd also be MUCH better off using a `List<string>` instead of array.

Comment: Hi I am just using a the .txt format and would it be easier to get the data from the file to add into the List<string> than using an array ?

Comment: Yes, but what is the text that you're storing? You're not telling us how it can be split to go into different "slots" of the collection. A `List` is better than an array because the length is dynamic. If you have an 11th object to store in your array, your current program will blow up.

Comment: krillgar's question is what is in the text file.  Is it just the text of questions?  Is there other information like question IDs, etc?

Comment: Oh right ok sorry I thought he meant what was the file type, there are two fields which is id and questions with an example 1, "QuestionTest"

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you edited your question to include a few lines of your `myFile.txt`.

Comment: Apologies again here are a few lines of my text file :-

Comment: "questions_id","questions"
1,"What is the correct element for Gold ?"
2,"What is the correct element for Hydrogen?"
3,"What is the correct element for Oxygen?"

Comment: Hi even though I just commented with a few line of the text file this is actually shown above in Sample Data

Comment: Instead of `ReadTextAsync()` you probably want [`ReadLinesAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readlinesasync.aspx). For which you iterate over this collection and split the string on `,`.

Answer (score 1):

string[] questions = File.ReadAllLines("ms-appx:///Assets/Questions/myFile.txt");